# overloading readline() in c#

Tags: c#, overloading, readline

You can limit the user to input up to a certain key press in C++ using:

```
istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );
```

Is the same thing possible with `Console.ReadLine()` in C# ?  If not then is there any way to overload or override it ?

Comment: You mean `Console.ReadLine`?  If so then no, it's a static method. I would suggest using `Console.Read` in a loop instead and checking each character.

Comment: Sounds like you might be looking for `Console.OpenStandardInput`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kdtbb63(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can intercept the characters yourself and validate them. There may be a better way, but here's one approach.

First, create a method that gets a character from the user and validates it against a list of acceptable characters (if the character entered by the user isn't in the list, then back up, write a space over their input, and try again):

```
/// <summary>
/// Prompts the user for input, and returns the first valid character they type.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="validInput">A list of valid characters. 
/// All characters will be accepted if this is null or empty.</param>
/// <param name="prompt">An optional prompt to display to the user.</param>
/// <returns>The first valid character entered by the user.</returns>
private static char ReadCharRestricted(ICollection<char> validInput = null, 
    string prompt = null)
{
    // Show prompt
    if (prompt != null) Console.Write(prompt);
    var cursorLeft = Console.CursorLeft;
    var input = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

    // Get input character, ignoring any that don't exist in 'validInput'
    while (validInput != null && validInput.Any() && !validInput.Contains(input))
    {
        Console.CursorLeft = cursorLeft;
        Console.Write(' ');
        Console.CursorLeft--;
        input = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
    }

    return input;
}
```

Next, we can write a method that will get a full line of text from the user by leveraging this method. Basically, we continue to get characters from the user and append them to a string until they enter the end of line character. At this point, we return the string to the caller (unless the string is empty and the caller specified to not allow empty strings):

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a line of text from the user, restricted to specific characters.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="validInput">Characters that the user is allowed to enter.</param>
/// <param name="prompt">An optional prompt to display to the user.</param>
/// <param name="allowEmpty">If true, allows empty string input.</param>
/// <returns>The line of text entered by the user.</returns>
private static string ReadLineRestricted(List<char> validInput = null, 
    string prompt = null, bool allowEmpty = true)
{
    // Show prompt
    if (prompt != null) Console.Write(prompt);

    // Ensure we capture end-of-line characters
    if (validInput == null) validInput = new List<char>();
    if (!validInput.Contains('\n')) validInput.Add('\n');
    if (!validInput.Contains('\r')) validInput.Add('\r');

    // Capture valid characters until the end of the line
    string output = string.Empty;
    while(true)
    {
        var input = ReadCharRestricted(validInput);

        if (input == '\n' || input == '\r')
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(output) || allowEmpty) break;
            Console.CursorLeft = prompt?.Length ?? 0;                    
        }
        else
        {
            output += input;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    return output;
}
```

**Usage**

Example usage of these methods might look like:

```
// Get a single vowel character from the user
var vowels = new List<char> { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y' };
char userVowel = ReadCharRestricted(vowels, "Enter a vowel: ");
Console.WriteLine($"\nYou entered the vowel: {userVowel}\n");

// Get any number of numeric characters from the user
var numbers = "0123456789".ToList(); // Another way to create a list of characters
string userNumber = ReadLineRestricted(numbers, "Enter your favorite number: ", false);
Console.WriteLine($"Your favorite number is: {userNumber}");

// Wait for input before closing
Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

**Output**

Well, you can't really tell from the output, but I tried entering non-vowel and non-numeric input at these prompts, and it was discarded:

[image]